# Create multiple textbox dynamically in single form using c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, textbox, class-library

My aim is to create a .dll file dynamically having TextBox,Button which can be used by anyone in a program using Visual C#.

It would get created in Class Library, No WFA tools would get used.

I need help in creating a form which can generate multiple TextBox according to the attributes provided by the user.

1)No of TextBox
2)Location
3)Size etc

Code

**CLASS.CS**

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;


namespace Forms
{
public class TextForm : Form
{
    public TextBox txtBox1;        
    public TextForm(int a, int b, int c, int d, string e)
    {

        Form f1 = new Form();
        txtBox1 = new TextBox();
        txtBox1.Visible = true;
        //f1.ActiveControl=txtBox1;
        f1.Controls.Add(txtBox1);
        txtBox1.Focus();
        f1.Visible = true;
            txtBox1.Size = new Size(a, b);
            txtBox1.Location = new Point(c, d);
            txtBox1.Text = (e).ToString();
            this.Controls.Add(txtBox1);
            txtBox1.Visible = true;

    }
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    { 
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    }
  }}
```

**PROGRAM.CS**

```
using System;
using Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
class Program
{

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        TextForm Box1 = (new TextForm(150, 14, 20, 32, "This is a TextBox 1"));
        TextForm Box2 = (new TextForm(180, 34, 40, 52, "This is a TextBox 2"));

    }}}
```

What should be the code?

Comment: Putting the text box on the form.. you've made a box (Box1, and 2) but you've nut put them anywhere.  as a result you wont see them.  You also havent made the form, and started it. You also potentially wanted to make those boxes from inside the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a **Form** for each **TextBox**. This is not what you want, provided that you plan to have forms with multiple text boxes.

I see two possibilities: you either want to create a) a textbox that you can easily add to your form, or b) a form with textboxes.

```
public class TextInput : Form
{
    public TextBox TxtBox {
        get; private set;
    }

    public Control Container {
        get; private set;
    }

    public TextInput(Control c, int a, int b, int c, int d, string e)
    {
        this.Container = c;
        this.TxtBox = new TextBox();

        var txtBox1 = this.TxtBox;
        txtBox1.Visible = true;
        c.Controls.Add(txtBox1);
        txtBox1.Focus();
        txtBox1.Size = new Size(a, b);
        txtBox1.Location = new Point(c, d);
        txtBox1.Text = (e).ToString();
        txtBox1.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

You'd use this as follows:

```
var f = new Form();
var txtBox1 = new TextInput( f, 100, 25, 10, 10, "Name" );
var txtBox1 = new TextInput( f, 100, 25, 10, 50, "Age" );
var txtBox1 = new TextInput( f, 100, 25, 10, 100, "Address" );
var txtBox1 = new TextInput( f, 100, 25, 10, 150, "Phone" );
```

The second possibility is much more interesting, in my opinion. You want to create a special Form that automatically adds text boxes as soon a you call a simple method. I'm going to simplify your code, though. It is not a good idea (at all), to use absolute positioning in your forms.

The following creates a form with text boxes and their labels. The textboxes occupy the whole width of the form. This is achieved by using a **TableLayoutPanel** in which a **Panel** *subPanel* is used for each row. 
This *subPanel* holds a label and a text box.

```
public class InputForm: Form {
        public InputForm()
        {
            this.Panel = new TableLayoutPanel{ Dock = DockStyle.Fill };            
            this.textBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
            this.Controls.Add( this.Panel );
        }

        public TextBox AddTextBox(string label)
        {
            var subPanel = new Panel { Dock = DockStyle.Top };
            var lblLabel = new Label { Text = label, Dock = DockStyle.Left };
            var tbEdit = new TextBox{ Dock = DockStyle.Fill };

            subPanel.Controls.Add( tbEdit );
            subPanel.Controls.Add( lblLabel );
            this.Panel.Controls.Add( subPanel );

            return tbEdit;
        }

        public TableLayoutPanel Panel {
            get; private set;
        }

        public TextBox[] TextBoxes {
            get {
                return this.textBoxes.ToArray();
            }
        }

        private List<TextBox> textBoxes;
    }
```

You can use this with the following simple code:

```
        var form = new InputForm();

        var tbName = form.AddTextBox( "Name" );
        var tbAge = form.AddTextBox( "Age" );
        var tbAddress = form.AddTextBox( "Address" );

        form.Show();
        Application.Run( form );
```

[image: The resulting form.]

If you'd like to give a few attributes to the text boxes to be created (colors, font, bold...), then you have two ways. The first one is to add parameters to the `AddTextBox()` method, though that would not scalate well as long as the number of attributes grows. The alternative is to create a **TextBoxAttributes** class, which will hold the configuring attributes for a given **TextBox**.

```
public class InputForm: Form {
    public class TextBoxAttributes {
        public TextBoxAttributes() {
            this.ForeColor = DefaultForeColor;
            this.BackColor = DefaultBackColor;
            this.Font = DefaultFont;
        }

        public Color ForeColor {
            get; set;
        }

        public Color BackColor {
            get; set;
        }

        public Font Font {
            get; set;
        }

        public bool Bold {
            get {
                return this.Font.Bold;
            }
            set {
                var style = FontStyle.Regular;

                if ( value ) {
                    style = FontStyle.Bold;
                }

                this.Font = new Font( this.Font, style );
            }
        }

        public bool Italic {
            get {
                return this.Font.Bold;
            }
            set {
                var style = FontStyle.Regular;

                if ( value ) {
                    style = FontStyle.Italic;
                }

                this.Font = new Font( this.Font, style );
            }
        }

        public bool Underline {
            get {
                return this.Font.Bold;
            }
            set {
                var style = FontStyle.Regular;

                if ( value ) {
                    style = FontStyle.Underline;
                }

                this.Font = new Font( this.Font, style );
            }
        }

        public float FontSize {
            get {
                return this.Font.Size;
            }
            set {
                this.Font = new Font( this.Font.FontFamily, value );
            }
        }
    }

    // ... more things...

    public TextBox AddTextBox(string label)
        => this.AddTextBox( label, new TextBoxAttributes() );

    public TextBox AddTextBox(string label, TextBoxAttributes attr)
    {
        var subPanel = new Panel { Dock = DockStyle.Top };
        var lblLabel = new Label { Text = label, Dock = DockStyle.Left };
        var tbEdit = new TextBox{
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            ForeColor = attr.ForeColor,
            BackColor = attr.BackColor,
            Font = attr.Font
        };

        subPanel.Controls.Add( tbEdit );
        subPanel.Controls.Add( lblLabel );
        this.Panel.Controls.Add( subPanel );

        return tbEdit;
    }

    // ... more things...
}
```

The main code would be:

```
        public static void Main()
        {
            var form = new InputForm();

            var tbName = form.AddTextBox( "Name", new InputForm.TextBoxAttributes {
                ForeColor = Color.Yellow,
                BackColor = Color.Blue
            });
            var tbAge = form.AddTextBox( "Age", new InputForm.TextBoxAttributes {
                ForeColor = Color.Green,
                BackColor = Color.Black,
                Bold = true
            });
            var tbAddress = form.AddTextBox( "Address" );

            form.Show();
            Application.Run( form );
        }
```

[image: Text boxes with modified attributes.]

Hope this helps.

Comment: That first code is doing really strange stuff. You named the class `TextInput` but its constructor `TextForm`. And that class shouldn't be a form at all. In fact, just a static toolset function to construct the TextBox and add it to the Form would do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about the name mistake. About the static toolset, yes, you're right, but I tried to set myself inside the context that the op gave to me. Since I did not fully understood his intentions, I gave two different answers following his code.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. Have used the second code. I am trying to define and change the Size,Color of each TextBox. Its not changing. Can you suggest me the way do so

Comment: I've expanded my answer to cover text boxes' colors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48899382/single-event-handler-for-multiple-combobox

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to switch to WPF this will become a lot easier, since you can profit from Autolayout and Bindings.

You could easily switch the Wrappanel for a StackPanel or a DockPanel.

The class will create a View based on the public properties of the handed over object. You might have to add additional Types to the Types-Dictionary. In my case those two where sufficient.

Create a Property of the DynamicControl and Bind to it in XAML.

```
XAML:
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=DynView}" />

public ViewModel
{
  public UserControl DynView {get; private set};

  private ModelType _model;

  public ViewModel(ModelType model)
  {
    _model = model;
    DynView = new DynamicControl<ModelType>(_model);
  }

}

public class DynamicControl<T> : UserControl 
{

    static DynamicControl()
    {
        Types[typeof(bool)] = (binding) =>
        {
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
            cb.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty,binding);
            return cb;
        };

        Types[typeof(String)] = (binding) =>
        {
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
            return tb;
        };

       // add additional Types if necessary
    }

    private T _model; 
    public DynamicControl(T model)
    {
        _model = model;
        WrapPanel wp = new WrapPanel();
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in model.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            Grid g = new Grid();
            g.Margin = new Thickness(5, 5, 25, 5);
            g.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            g.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
            g.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
            g.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock() { Text = pi.Name };
            tb.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            Grid.SetColumn(tb, 0);
            Grid.SetRow(tb, 0);
            g.Children.Add(tb);
            System.Windows.FrameworkElement uie = GetUiElement(pi);
            uie.Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 0, 0);
            uie.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            Grid.SetColumn(uie, 1);
            Grid.SetRow(uie, 0);
            g.Children.Add(uie);
            wp.Children.Add(g);
        }
        this.Content = wp;
    }

    private FrameworkElement GetUiElement(PropertyInfo pi)
    {
        System.Windows.Data.Binding binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding(pi.Name);
        binding.Source = _model;
        Func<System.Windows.Data.Binding, FrameworkElement> func;
        FrameworkElement uie = null;
        if (Types.TryGetValue(pi.PropertyType, out func))
            uie = func(binding);
        else
            uie = Types[typeof(String)](binding);

        return uie;
    }

    private static Dictionary<Type, Func<System.Windows.Data.Binding, FrameworkElement>> Types = new Dictionary<Type, Func<System.Windows.Data.Binding, FrameworkElement>>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going at this all wrong. Just define your dimensions and text in advance, put them in a data class, and then feed a list of those data classes to your form constructor so it can construct them all on the fly.

The data class:

```
public class TextboxInfo
{
    public Int32 Width { get; set; }
    public Int32 Height { get; set; }
    public Int32 X { get; set; }
    public Int32 Y { get; set; }
    public String Text { get; set; }

    public TextboxInfo(Int32 w, Int32 h, Int32 x, Int32 y, String text)
    {
        this.Width = w;
        this.Height = h
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y
        this.Text = text;
    }
}
```

The code to construct the form:

```
public class TextForm : Form
{
    public TextBox[] TextBoxes
    {
         get { return _textBoxes.ToArray(); }
    }
    private List<TextBox> _textBoxes;

    public TextForm(TextboxInfo[] textboxes, Int32 padX, Int32 padY)
    {
        _textBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
        Int32 reqWidth = 0;
        Int32 reqHeight = 0;
        foreach (TextboxInfo tbi in textboxes)
        {
            reqWidth = Math.Max(reqWidth, tbi.X + tbi.Width);
            reqHeight = Math.Max(reqHeight, tbi.Y + tbi.Height);
            TextBox txtB = new TextBox();
            txtB.Size = new Size(tbi.Width, tbi.Height);
            txtB.Location = new Point(tbi.X, tbi.Y);
            txtB.Text = tbi.Text;
            _textBoxes.Add(txtB);
            this.Controls.Add(txtB);
        }
        // You may want to add some kind of OK button at the end here (based on reqHeight)
        // and link that to a click listener that closes the form.
        // Don't forget to adjust your reqHeight to the added height of that button!

        // ...

        // Set form to the minimum needed size according to its elements.
        this.Size = new Size(reqWidth + padX, reqHeight + padY);
    }
}
```

The calling code:

```
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        TextboxInfo[] info = new TextboxInfo[2];
        info[0] = new TextboxInfo(150, 14, 20, 32, "This is a TextBox 1");
        info[1] = new TextboxInfo(180, 34, 40, 52, "This is a TextBox 2");
        TextForm frm = new TextForm(info, 20, 32);
        frm.ShowDialog();
        // Now you can access the form's text box values through frm.TextBoxes[i].Text
    }
}
```

Mind you, this whole system may seem useful at first, but consider that none of the text boxes have labels on them. Just starting values.

I've made systems for custom data before in a project I created, to generate a custom save options dialog depending on the chosen file type to save to, since each file type needed specific options.

[image]

Realistically, you'd create a form with some kind of description at the top and an OK and a Cancel button at the bottom, with a panel in between which has its vertical scrollbar set to enable-when-needed. Then you can dynamically put different custom controls in there to support different data types, like say, a checkbox, a text field, a numeric field, et cetera. They'll automatically be listed vertically in the list simply by keeping track of each control's height to get the next control's Y-offset, and if they'd exceed the form size the panel will make sure you can scroll down.

All you'd give to the form are objects of a data class like the one I showed, but without positioning data. They'd have a type, to figure out what kind of custom control to create, a description text, a default value to set the input control to, and possibly some kind of initialisation value, for example, to limit the range of a numeric value, or, as in the image I showed, values for a dropdown list.